# Boilerplate code for MVC web-app?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, boilerplate

I've never had the joy of putting together a java web-app in the MVC form myself before?

Stopping shy of a [letmegooglethatforyou.com](http://letmegooglethatforyou.com) request, would anyone here be able to recommend a good place where I might find a good boilerplate source to learn from?

I seem to learn best that way...

With Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I learn from reading source code as well. Probably why I've failed each time I've tried to learn C#.

Answer (score 2):

This [Spring MVC step-by-step](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html) article is a tutorial on putting together a webapp with Spring MVC, the Spring framework, and JDBC, using HSQL.

Answer (score 2):

The Spring MVC [Petstore](http://www.springsource.org/download/) (various versions included in the full spring distribution) is exactly such project. Moreover, it has been heavily used as an example and there are several versions of it that highlight boilerplate code for various scenarios ([Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html), [DWR](http://code.google.com/p/spring-petstore/), etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Look at some successful web MVC frameworks: Spring, Wicket, Struts (okay, not *that* successful), etc.

Comment: Agreed.  It was the first, so that counts for something.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/java/online/notes-java/GUI/structure/40mvc.html , http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/07/07/genericmvc.html , http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html and basically anything else you turn up with a search for "MVC java" contain plenty of source code you can peruse to learn the basics of MVC in Java. These all contain some small examples of simple MVC that you can look at quickly.

So, to answer your question, the best place to find stuff like this is a neat website called http://www.google.com . Seriously, you can go to Oracle's website as well and look at some of the docs.

Comment: I don't really understand. Why -1?